# где ставить запятую

Tags: пунктуация

А объяснить твои визиты к нам или наши — к тебе, обыкновенной дружеской связью — будет очень легко.

или А объяснить твои визиты к нам, или наши — к тебе обыкновенной дружеской связью — будет очень легко.

илии вообще - А объяснить твои визиты к нам, или наши — к тебе, обыкновенной дружеской связью — будет очень легко.

Помогите, пожалуйста, правильно расставить запятые

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Знаки препинания здесь не нужны:

*А объяснить твои визиты к нам или наши  к тебе // обыкновенной дружеской связью // будет (можно) очень легко.*

**Тире** на месте пропущенного слова (*наши к тебе*) можно не ставить, так как **нет паузы**.

**Структура предложения:** *объяснить визиты дружеской связью будет легко.*

Предложение простое, неосложненное, поэтому **нет грамматики, которую нужно обозначать знаками препинания.**

Объяснить — подлежащее, будет легко — сказуемое, дружеской связью — дополнение.

Предложение делится **произносительными паузами** на смысловые отрезки, но эти паузы запятой не обозначаются.